# Making a slanted pane that is more than a simple square with translation

Tags: modeling, faces, edges

I need a slanted pane for my model.

Normally I would just select one edge and translate it upwards (which I would need to do to keep the delta-width and -depth while changing the height), but my problem is that this shape needs a hole, and therefore this way of slanting it doesn't work.

It's kind of hard to phrase this question properly, so I made this crude drawing https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6WEC.png

[image]

In the top, there's a simple square pane, one of it's side is being moved up so it ends in the way I would like it to be.

On the bottom, there's the same pane but with a hole in it, and because the vertices of the hole aren't being translated, the hole itself stays where it is while the outer edges are how they are supposed to be, therefore deforming the whole shape.

Is there a way or a tool to raise that one edge and all the other vertices on that plane in a manner so the plane stays flat?

Comment: Do you need good topology? If not use a (2D) bezier curve object instead, if you do open the hole **after** slanting.

Comment: It would also help if I could make the hole after slanting, maybe with some "remove intersecting parts" option I'm unaware of, making the slanted pane, adding a cylinger and removing the intersecting parts.

Comment: You can insert the hole afterward using either **Knife Project** or **Boolean Modifier**.

Comment: You can model the mesh normally and then in Edit mode select it, select the edge on the right on the screenshot, choose pivot point as Active Element and rotate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my alternate approach you may try, that uses ***proportional editing (linear)*** and some scaling.
[image]

Select the very end vertices of the plane, enable the *proportional editing* (set its mode to ***Linear***) and translate upwards.
[image]

With the transform orientation set to ***Normal*** select all the faces of the plane and press <kbd>S</kbd> and then <kbd>Z</kbd> twice (to transform along the normal Z coordinate).
[image]

BTW @Duarte Farrajota Ramos 's method involving curves works as well. Just add a curve and set its angle to fit your needs. Then give the plane a ***Curve Modifier*** with a curve as a target.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Select an edge of the plane and use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> and choose "Cursor to selected".
[image: Cursor to selected]

Step 2: Rotate on an axis choosing using the 3D cursor.
[image: Rotate options]